# Resend SerialPort commands in c# based on timer

Tags: c#, timer, serial-port

I have a 
    SerialPort ComPort = new SerialPort();

which is initialized from Windows Form to "COM1", and the event handler as:

```
ComPort.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived_1);

private void port_DataReceived_1(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    InputData = ComPort.ReadExisting();
    if (InputData != String.Empty)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextCallback(SetText), new object[] { InputData });
    }
}

private void SetText(string text)
{
    Response = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

}
```

In the Form I have

```
private byte[] Response = null;
private int MaxAttempts = 1
private int Attempts = 0;
private bool Launch = true;
```

Upon clicking a button control, I have:

```
    private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] BufferTest = new byte[1];
        BufferTest[0] = 1;

        System.Timers.Timer Temp = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
        Temp.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent; //See this function below
        Temp.Enabled = true;

        while (Response == null && Attempts < MaxAttempts)
        {
            if (Launch)
            {
                Launch = false;
                ComPort.Write(BufferTest, 0, BufferTest.Length);
            }
        }

        //Right here Response is still null despite there was bytes read at serial port
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Attempts++;
        Launch = true;
    }
```

At the end of the btnTest_Click method, Response is still null despite there was bytes read at serial port, and set Response. What happens is that SetText() is called after btnTest_Click finishes. I was expecting that SetText() is called upon event, then interrupting the while loop and so getting the response there.

Any help please???

Comment: Don't block the UI thread.  Instead, use `await`.

Comment: You are getting yourself into a lot of trouble, it doesn't work the way you think it does.  Using ReadExisting() like that is also very incorrect.  There is a simple and a hard way to do this, you must get the simple way working first.  With decent odds that it is good enough.  Stop using the DataReceived event, just call one of the Read methods right after you called Write().